# Possible inline "pre-assignment" operation?

Tags: java, variables, variable-assignment

Seeing that my understanding of computer science terminology is lacking, bear with me and correct me if misname a CS concept.

Is there a way to do something I would call *"inline post-assignment"* on variables? It's essentially the opposite flow of "inline pre-assignment". For example:

```
// some random number
int currentNumber = 0;

// e.g. of inline pre-assignment (assigns 5 to var before entering function)
doSomethingOnNumber(currentNumber = 5);

// e.g. of envisioned inline "post-assignment" 
// (assigns 5 to var after entering function)
doSomethingOnNumber(5 = currentNumber);

// And yes, I know I could just do something like:
doSomethingOnNumber(currentNumber);
currentNumber = 5;

// But that is rather boring ;D
```

It may be a crazy question (seeing that the equals sign is just that: assigns right hand data to left hand variable), but maybe there's some Java framework that can preform that?

The main way this would be useful would be for something like:

```
private int myNum = 0;

public int resetNum (int newNum) {
    return myNum;

    myNum = newNum; // (this never happens because of the return)
}
```

While a good design shouldn't need to have something like this, you might have a method specification that requires it both reset a counter and return its value.

Comment: Can you give an example of why you would want to do that?

Comment: Even if a symbol was introduced to do this I'm having a hard time coming up with a good reason to do so. I'd also like to see an example where this would enhance readability.

Comment: I currently can't think of a example where this concept could be used effectively, and it would impair readability drastically. I was just curious as to the limits of inline variable assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest you can get is to use the pre-(in|de)crement (`++`|`--`) operators.

```
int currentNumber = 0;

// pre-increment (function receives 1)
doSomethingOnNumber(++currentNumber);

// vs
currentNumber = 0;

// post-increment (function receives 0)
doSomethingOnNumber(currentNumber++);
```

Generally speaking, though, "boring" code is more desirable than "clever" code. Boring code tends to be clearer, simpler, and easier to maintain.

Comment: Relevant: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=clever+code, especially [Why is cleverness considered harmful in programming by some people?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/25276/why-is-cleverness-considered-harmful-in-programming-by-some-people).

Comment: Agreed, "boring" code is better than "clever" code. It took me a while to figure that out, but I now understand how important it is. I thought it was a interesting idea though; I guess wanted to understand the boundaries of java's inline operation ability.

Answer (score 1):

Have the method return the required value:

```
currentNumber = doSomethingOnNumber(currentNumber);
```

If the calling site knows the required value, pass it to the method:

```
currentNumber = doSomethingOnNumber(currentNumber, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with for the situation mentioned above is:

```
private int myNum = 0; 

public int resetNum (int newNum) {
    try {
        return myNum; 
    } finally {
        myNum = newNum; //this happens despite return because of the finally clause
    }
}
```

I am unsure if this actually works, because I have not yet had a chance to test it, and I am relatively new to java.